# How to display several things inside graphic?

Tags: plotting

`Epilog` and `Inset` can display something on the plot, but what about several things? I used them in a simple example to place a label on the plot:

```
data3 = Table[{x, x^2 + 2}, {x, 0, 5}];
Show[Plot[x^2, {x, 0, 5}, PlotRange -> All], 
 ListPlot[data3, PlotStyle -> Red], ImageSize -> Large, Frame -> True,
  Epilog -> Inset[Framed[Style["B", 15]], Scaled[{0.4, 0.8}]]]
```

How can I display two framed text in other positions inside this plot? I tried another `Eplilog` but seems it doesn't work.

Comment: Make the value of `Epilog` a list containing `Inset`s, or whatever you're after, in it.

Comment: Thanks< please add an answer

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Add all the items you want in the `Epilog` to it as a list:

```
data3 = Table[{x, x^2 + 2}, {x, 0, 5}];
Show[Plot[x^2, {x, 0, 5}, PlotRange -> All],
 ListPlot[data3, PlotStyle -> Red],
 ImageSize -> Large, Frame -> True,
 Epilog ->
  {Inset[Framed[Style["A", 15]], Scaled[{0.8, 0.4}]], 
   Inset[Framed[Style["B", 15]], Scaled[{0.4, 0.8}]]}]
```

[image]

Answer (score 8):

Use [`Overlay`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Overlay.html) to stack anything, [`Show`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Show.html) to stack [`Graphics`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Graphics.html) and [`Plot`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Plot.html), and as mentioned by @kirma, [`Epilog`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Epilog.html) accepts [`List`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/List.html) as argument, so you can put many thing there.

```
Overlay[
    {
        ExampleData[{"AerialImage", "Earth"}],
        Show[
            Plot[
                x^2
                , {x, 0, 5}
                , PlotRange -> All
            ], 
            ListPlot[
                data3
                , PlotStyle -> Red
            ]
            Graphics[
                Table[
                    {
                        Hue[t/20], 
                        Circle[{Cos[2 Pi t/20]+2, 10+Sin[2 Pi t/20]}]
                    }
                    , {t,20}
                ]
            ]
            , ImageSize -> Large
            , Frame -> True
            , Epilog -> Map[
                Inset[Framed[Style[RandomWord[], 15]], Scaled[#]]&, 
                RandomReal[{0,1},{10,2}]
            ]
            , Background-> Directive[White,Opacity[0.5]]
        ]
    }
]
```

[image]

Comment: This graphic would make for some great Wolfram merch!